# Instantiate an object so it can be shared with multiple directives

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, angularjs-scope, ng-style

**What I am doing:** I am creating two attribute directives: One moves an element to the left, and another centers an element on the page. See code below. Notice that I'm manipulating `ng-style` to set those css properties (moving the element to the left, and centering on the page).

**The Problem:**
When I use *both* directives on an element, the second directive's `scope.style={}` obviously *overwrites* the first one.
This means that I'm not able to apply both `ng-style`/attributes at the same time.

**My question:**
What is an easy way to instantiate the `scope.style` object so that I can use it in both directives without recreating the object?

I'm trying to find a simple solution that can be scaled easily for multiple element directives *without* writing tons of messy code. (I don't want to create a special controller inside every directive to accommodate sharing the scope.style object).

Please advise. Thanks a lot!

---

**Here is the html:**
*The data is from a json file, but that's not important here.*

```
<!-- The Element: -->
<started-box center-page keepleft screen="screen[3]"></started-box>

<!-- The Template: -->
<div id="{{screen.id}}" ng-style="$parent.style">
    Some content goes here.
</div>
```

**Here are the AngularJS code snippets:**

```
// Two Attribute directives:
app.directive("centerPage", function () {
    return function (scope, element, attrs) {
        var winW = window.innerWidth;
        var winH = window.innerHeight;
        var boxW = 370;
        var boxH = 385;

        scope.style = {};
        scope.style.left = (winW / 2) - (boxW / 2);
        scope.style.top = (winH / 2) - (boxH / 2);
    }
});
app.directive("keepleft", function () {
    return function (scope, element, attrs) {
        scope.style = {};
        scope.style.cursor = 'default';
        scope.style.transform = 'translateX(-60%)';
    }
});

// Directive for the template:
app.directive("startedBox", [function () {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            screen: '='
        },
        templateUrl: dir + 'templates/directives/started-box.html'
    };
}]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a style service and inject it into both directives. Services are excellent for sharing states between directives/controllers.

Comment: I added the following service. Thing is that the same style object is being shared across all elements using either one of the attribute directives. That means that if an element uses only one of the attribute directives it is still having both applied to it. How do I isolate this to recreate the style object once per element? Thanks a lot for your answer.

app.factory("style", function(){
    return{
        style: {}
    }
});